# How do I search for an attribute using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: html, beautifulsoup, python-re

I am trying to scrape a that contains the following HTML.

```
<div class="FeedCard urn:publicid:ap.org:db2b278b7e4f9fea9a2df48b8508ed14 Component-wireStory-0-2-116 card-0-2-117" data-key="feed-card-wire-story-with-image" data-tb-region-item="true">
      
<div class="FeedCard urn:publicid:ap.org:2f23aa3df0f2f6916ad458785dd52c59 Component-wireStory-0-2-116 card-0-2-117" data-key="feed-card-wire-story-with-image" data-tb-region-item="true">
```

As you can see, "FeedCard " is something they have in common. Therefore, I am trying to use a regular expression in conjunction with BeautifulSoup. Here is the code I've tried.

```
pattern = r"\AFeedCard"



for card in soup.find('div', 'class'==re.compile(pattern)):
    print(card)
    print('**********')
```

I'm expecting it to give me each on of the divs from above, with the asterisks separating them. Instead it is giving me the entire HTML of the page in a single instance

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use regular expression here. Just use CSS selector or BS4 Api:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html = """\
<div class="FeedCard urn:publicid:ap.org:db2b278b7e4f9fea9a2df48b8508ed14 Component-wireStory-0-2-116 card-0-2-117" data-key="feed-card-wire-story-with-image" data-tb-region-item="true">
Item 1
</div>

<div class="FeedCard urn:publicid:ap.org:2f23aa3df0f2f6916ad458785dd52c59 Component-wireStory-0-2-116 card-0-2-117" data-key="feed-card-wire-story-with-image" data-tb-region-item="true">
Item 2
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

for card in soup.select(".FeedCard"):
    print(card.text.strip())
```

Prints:

```
Item 1
Item 2
```